# How to multiply two values in angularjs in html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a demo of AngularJS, which converts two units. Basically I have two dropdowns with unit values and want to multiply the selected values from the dropdowns. I created a jsfiddle for my code, can anybody please help me to figure it out.

**fiddle**

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jmakwana/Td2NZ/1492/)
HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="address in addresses">
        Billing State:
        <select
            ng-model="address.state"
            ng-options="state.lookupCode as state.description for state in lov_state"></select>
        <tt>State selected: {{address.state}}</tt>
    </div>

</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.addresses = [
        {'state': 'AL'},
        {'state': 'CA'},
        {'state': 'FL'}
    ];

    $scope.lov_state = [
        {'lookupCode': 'AL', 'description': 'Alabama'},
        {'lookupCode': 'FL', 'description': 'Florida'},
        {'lookupCode': 'CA', 'description': 'California'},
        {'lookupCode': 'DE', 'description': 'Delaware'}
    ];
});
```

My code at fiddle is as below:
[My JSFiddleworking demo](http://jsfiddle.net/td2nz/)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code in the question (not just in the fiddle) and fix the fiddle link.

Comment: What does that fiddle have to do with converting units?

Comment: Your code in question body is not same as fiddle.

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to do. What are you trying to multiply?

Comment: Your new fiddle at the top doesn't make any sense either. I could presume that KM, MI and CM mean kilometers, miles and centimeters respectively, but then the 1, 100 and 1000 doesn't make any sense. I'm VTCing this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So close! just forgot to do the sum

update fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/du4anx89/1/)

you just missed `= {{address.state * unit.state}}`